# How to find a string in list of tuples using scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following list:

```
 List(
  (List("vmname"),"myNetwork3",10,"vSwitch0",List(),"192.168.20.2","cisco WS-C3560E-48PD","GigabitEthernet0/43","sky"),
  (List("vmname"),"myNetwork",0,"vSwitch0",List("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"),"192.168.20.2","cisco WS-C3560E-48PD","GigabitEthernet0/43","sky")
)
```

And I want to find string `"name1"` in list element of list.

I want following output:

```
(List("vmname"),"myNetwork",0,"vSwitch0",List("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"),"192.168.20.2","cisco WS-C3560E-48PD","GigabitEthernet0/43","sky")
```

How to get above output using scala?

Comment: Is this an assignment? There are two of you asking very similar questions

Comment: @paul No.. I also find similar question.. I am able to find string in list but not able to find it in list of list

Answer (score 3):

```
l.filter(._5 contains "name1")
```

Return all entries with "name1"  in the list that is the 5th element of each entry